# Files for use in Feature activation of a web application scoped feature SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-feature

Is it possible to access local system files in a feature activation event scoped at web application level?

Answer (score 0):

YES, I tried it indirectly instantiating a sp timer job process that streams a temp File getted from a another webservice method.
Maybe this is also possible without this complex timer job scenario, but with the timer job it works perfectly.